# SQL Lag to calculate datetime_diff between records is very slow

Tags: sql, performance, google-bigquery, window-functions

I work at a company that delivers groceries B2C and in order to improve operational efficiency we have started with stacking orders (taking multiple orders per ride). **I'd like to calculate the time between orders that are stacked.**
The data looks like this:

| order_id | stack_id | delivered |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-01-01T13:00:00 |
| 2 | 1 | 2022-01-01T13:05:00 |
| 3 | 1 | 2022-01-01T13:12:00 |
| 4 |  | 2022-01-01T14:00:00 |
| 5 | 2 | 2022-01-01T14:10:00 |
| 6 | 2 | 2022-01-01T14:17:00 |
| 7 |  | 2022-01-01T16:00:00 |
| ... | ... | ... |

*Orders with stack_id null is just an order that is not stacked.*

The bellow code is how I've set it up now. The problem is that the window function with *order by* seems to require much memory when running it in production and will only get worse with more orders. **Does anyone know a more innovative way of doing this?**

```sql
with vals as (
  select
    1 as order_id,
    1 as stack_id,
    datetime('2022-01-01T13:00:00') as delivered
  union all
  select
    2 as order_id,
    1 as stack_id,
    datetime('2022-01-01T13:05:00') as delivered
  union all
  select
    3 as order_id,
    1 as stack_id,
    datetime('2022-01-01T13:12:00') as delivered
  union all
  select
    4 as order_id,
    null as stack_id,
    datetime('2022-01-01T14:00:00') as delivered
  union all
  select
    5 as order_id,
    2 as stack_id,
    datetime('2022-01-01T14:10:00') as delivered
  union all
  select
    6 as order_id,
    2 as stack_id,
    datetime('2022-01-01T14:17:00') as delivered
  union all
  select
    7 as order_id,
    null as stack_id,
    datetime('2022-01-01T16:00:00') as delivered
),

last_order as (
  select
    *,
    if(stack_id is not null, lag(delivered) over (partition by stack_id order by delivered), null) as previous_order_delivered
  from vals
),

time_between_dropoffs as (
  select
    *,
    datetime_diff(delivered, previous_order_delivered, second) as seconds_between_dropoff
  from last_order
)

select * from time_between_dropoffs
order by delivered
```

This is the output:

| order_id | stack_id | delivered | previous_order_delivered | seconds_between_dropoffs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-01-01T13:00:00 |  |  |
| 2 | 1 | 2022-01-01T13:05:00 | 2022-01-01T13:00:00 | 300 |
| 3 | 1 | 2022-01-01T13:12:00 | 2022-01-01T13:05:00 | 420 |
| 4 |  | 2022-01-01T14:00:00 |  |  |
| 5 | 2 | 2022-01-01T14:10:00 |  |  |
| 6 | 2 | 2022-01-01T14:17:00 | 2022-01-01T14:10:00 | 420 |
| 7 |  | 2022-01-01T16:00:00 |  |  |
| ... | ... | ... |  |  |

Comment: Hi - what you've outlined is the "correct" approach to solving this problem and should run without any issues. Does it run in an acceptable timeframe and, if it does, why do you care about high memory usage? If you have a high volume of data then, rather running the query over all your data each time, you could store the results of this query and update these results as/when you get new order/stack records

Comment: Thanks for the answer NickW! Yeah, I think I'll do incremental batch loads with this rather than rerun everything every day. But I thought I'd check with the internet before doing so if there is a smarter way